# How to create submodules with the Python C API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-c-api

I want to create the following module and object structure:

```
main_module
|
`--sub_module
   |
   +--ObjectOne
   |
   `--sub_sub_module
      |
      `--ObjectTwo
```

When I only had `main_module.sub_module` everything worked as it should, as I created an empty `__init__.py` inside the `main_module` folder (since `main_module` does not have any objects at the moment), and I placed `sub_module.so` next to it.

However, when I tried to create two separate c modules to make `main_module.sub_module.sub_sub_module` work (that is `sub_module.so` and `sub_sub_module.so`) and then I added two `__init__.py`s which both of them imported their extension modules relative to them, then I got into `ImportError`s (as wrappers around the `undefined symbol` error "raised" from the shared libraries), because `sub_sub_module` needs a few of the C-level definitions from `sub_module`. Which makes me think, it would be way more easier, to create a single shared library which somehow creates "virtual" modules inside it, instead of the unnecessary library linking..

So my question is: Is it possible? If so, how? Or, is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how you implemented all this; or better post some code?

Comment: @tynn it is quite large to post the whole thing here, but here is the repo: https://github.com/kitchenbudapest/hackathon/tree/master/fw/wrappers/python -- if you go a few folders up, in `kb` there is the C library I'm wrapping, and the link I provided is the python wrapper part only

Comment: ***um.. why the -1?***

Answer (score 2):

I think I got your problem now. For a long and detailed answer you should read [Providing a C API for an Extension Module](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#providing-a-c-api-for-an-extension-module).

> Portability therefore requires **not to make any assumptions about symbol visibility**. This means that all symbols in extension modules should be declared static, except for the module’s initialization function, in order to avoid name clashes with other extension modules [...]. And it means that symbols that should be accessible from other extension modules **must be exported in a different way**.

To achieve this you should use [Capsules](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/capsule.html). For these every function you want to use in another module should be stored inside a `void*` *array*. Then you create a capsule with `PyCapsule_New(void*, const char*, PyCapsule_Destructor)` using the *array* as first argument. This object must be added to your *sub_module*. Then you can call `PyCapsule_Import(const char*, int)` in your *sub_sub_module* to import the *array* and access the functions you need.

Comment: I'm already familiar with `Capsule`s -- as You can see, I use them for the `enum` values (PIN indices). However I've never thought of using them like you have suggested.. My other solution -- which I think can be better than the one you have provided -- is to create 3 shared libraries: 1) for common-data, 2) for sub_module, 3) for sub_sub_module => in this case there is no "Python overhead" where it is not necessary. IMHO `Capsule`s are there to make opaque C-level data passing *by the user* -- but here, the data is not necessarily used by the user directly. (+1 for the effort though!)

Comment: @PeterVaro it's from the official documentation. I was just paraphrasing. In my understanding `Capsule`s should always be used instead of exporting symbols and python overhead is quite insignificant since you're only importing it once. But if it's not python related data and functions I might also link to a "pure" C library instead.